# Like/as meaning difference in given context

Tags: adverbs

He treated me **like** a dog.

He treated me **as** a dog.

Here, do both sentences mean different things? Are **as** and **like** interchangeable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrases such as these are called **similes**. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile):

> Simile. A simile (/ˈsɪməli/) is a figure of speech that directly compares two things. Similes are a form of metaphor that explicitly use connecting words (such as like, as, so, than, or various verbs such as resemble), though these specific words are not always necessary.

Both words serve the same function in a simile, and are therefore interchangeable.

Comment: in this context, they are interchangeable. it depends on the context. 

one of the definitions of like is `in the same way that; as.`